# Add SearchView on Button click

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I declared SearchView:

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
searchView.setQueryHint("some text");
```

My goal is to add this searchview to the actionbar only after a button is clicked. It is not a menubutton. A normal button in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
searchView.setQueryHint("some text");

smenu=menu.add("smenu").setVisible(false).setActionView(searchView);
smenu.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Then in onClickListener:

```
smenu.expandActionView();
```

or

```
smenu.collapseActionView();
```

Comment: But you said you don't need it as a menu item.
>> "It is not a menubutton" I thought you did not need a search button on your ActionBar.

Comment: With this I don't have a button in the menu. Its visibility is set to false. But I can handle its ActionView through the specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
private ActionBar bar;

//....

SearchView searchView = new SearchView(bar.getThemedContext());
searchView.setQueryHint("some text");
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    // revert to normal menu
    bar.setDisplayOptions(your_opions);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
});

//...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // show custom view
    bar.setDisplayOptions(your_opions | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    bar.setCustomView(searchView);

}
```